# How to change response from text/plain to text/xml

Tags: wso2, plaintext

I have a service returns a text/plain content. The response message like:
RESP0Success"
But in ESB4.0.3, the response is like:

```
<text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;message&gt;&lt;MsgType&gt;RESP&lt;/MsgType&gt;&lt;ReturnCode&gt;0&lt;/ReturnCode&gt;&lt;ReturnMessage&gt;Success&lt;/ReturnMessage&gt;&lt;/message&gt;
 </text>
```

I set builder and formatter in axis2.xml. But no use.

```
<messageBuilder contentType="text/plain"             
class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder"/>
<messageFormatter contentType="text/plain"
class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter"/>
```

Can anyxone tell me how to set the builder and formatter in axis2.xml? My service config is:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TextPlain" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="ContentType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2" />
         <log level="full" />
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full" />
         <property name="ContentType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2" />
         <send />
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://172.20.28.206:8080/AAAService/recieveMsg" format="pox">
         </address>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, then I set

```
<property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
```

and now it works, if i call it from URL, it will return only text.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="RESTE" transports="http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://10.15.21.189:8180/contadorServicos/ola-mundo"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <parameter name="serviceType">proxy</parameter>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

Unfortunattely the Tryit functionality stoped working, now it giver the following error.

```
<parsererror xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/newlayout/xml/parsererror.xml">Erro no processamento de XML: formatação incorreta Posição: http://xxxxxxx/services/RESTE?tryit# Número da linha 1, coluna 221:
   <sourcetext>&lt;TryitProxyError h:status='SOAP envelope error' xmlns:h='http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy'&gt;org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'r' (code 114) in prolog; expected '&lt;'at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]&lt;/TryitProxyError&gt; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^</sourcetext>
</parsererror>
```

p.s: When I use other tools like SOAPUI, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the ContentType of your message. As the input from the HTTP will contain the Soap envelope and body, your content is being included inside such a  tag.

When you now tell your endpoint, that the message is of type text/plain, the PlainTextFormatter will convert it to real text and send it your endpoint (the axis2.xml is only the config - now you need to tell that you want to use now the PlainTextFormatter)

This line is missing:

```
<property name="ContentType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: I set ContentType, you can see the new service config. But no use, the response is:<text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;message&gt;&lt;header&gt;&lt;TransactionID&gt;1&lt;/TransactionID&gt;&lt;Timestamp&gt;2012-06-04 10:45:35&lt;/Timestamp&gt;&lt;OpCode&gt;IAG.BOSS_QUERY_DATA&lt;/OpCode&gt;&lt;MsgType&gt;RESP&lt;/MsgType&gt;&lt;ReturnCode&gt;0&lt;/ReturnCode&gt;&lt;ErrorMessage&gt;??&lt;/ErrorMessage&gt;&lt;/message&gt;
 </text>